# Rendering Animation in background?

Tags: rendering, animation

Can I render a scene in Blender in background while working on another scene in foreground? Rendering takes some time, but I do not want to watch an hour of animation rendering while I could edit the next scene. I tried doing so but my UI does not update when I change the frame number. Is there a way to work in parallel with a rendering job?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a render farm, so that an external computer does the rendering while you work on something else. Next, would be to render using the console (or command line) with no interface, and work on a second instance of blender. Keep in mind that the resources on your computer are limited. Using the computer while rendering will slow down the render (and make rendering times longer), but will make your computer less responsive for other tasks.

Comment: You can absolutely do that. Just have two blenders open, one rendering, and then another for you to work in. You *can* render and keep working in the same instance, but like you saw it does not always update everything.

Comment: @David is correct, If you are in Linux or Windows you can have multiple instances of blender open at the same time.

Comment: @cegaton you can also do this on a Mac. Just open a terminal, navigate to the directory Blender is in, and run `./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender`.

Comment: Render farm sounds interesting, do we have a HOWTO for setting one up?

Comment: @Kai There is a network render addon included with blender, read the [cgcookie page](https://cgcookie.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-renderfarm/) about setting one up, the video is paid but the page details most info you need. [Flamenco](https://www.flamenco.io/) is the BF created render farm if you want to put more effort into setting up a more professional one.

Comment: @Kai https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15365/1853